# Need advice with regards to mezzanine card for new HP bl460c gen8 blade

Tags: hp, iscsi, hp-proliant, blade-server

The new blade will connect to an iSCSI MSA2000 SAN with a 1Gb interconnect. Do I need both mezzanine slots populated? What ethernet card do you recommend?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need any additional mezzanine cards for the [HP ProLiant BL460c Gen8](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14208_div/14208_div.html#Overview) system to accommodate iSCSI use. This may depend slightly on which interconnects you're using in the C3000/C7000 blade chassis and what's already in use, but the system has onboard NICs available.

Comment: +1 -also be aware @mikedos that Gen8 mezz cards are very different to all previous generation cards, you can't swap between them, this has caught a number of people out.